# Class field axiom III-1 in Serre's "Local Fields"

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $F/E$ be a finite extension of local fields, and $N = N_{F/E} : F^* \to E^*$ be the norm map (it is continuos).
And consider an axiom:

> $N$ has closed image and compact kernel.

In the book, the author says that this condition is equivalent to that $N$ is proper.
But I can't show it.
Please help.

P.S. This condition holds in this case.
I use the word "axiom" because I use the explicit terminology for simplification (the author uses class field formation).
So please show the equivalence using only locally compactness, countability at infinity of $E, F$ and continuity of $N$.